# Type.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute> returns custom attributes in random order

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reflection, visual-studio-sdk

Consider following codes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class SampleAttribute : Attribute
{
     public String Name {get;set};
     public SampleAttribute(String testName)
     {
           Name = testName;
     }
}

[SampleAttribute("A")]
[SampleAttribute("B")]
public class Test
{

}

var attributes = typeof(Test).GetCustomAttributes<SampleAttribute>();
```

Unfortunately, the method ***"GetCustomAttributes"*** returns attributes in random order.

For example following code will print different results every time I run application.

```
foreach(var att in attributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(att.Name);
}
```

On time, first "A" then "B" another time vice versa.

Is there any solution for my problem ?

I'm not going to add a column such as order or anything like that, I'd like to solve the problem.

Environment: .NET 4.5.1 , Visual Studio 2012 Update 3 SDK , C# 5. Both Debug and Release modes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything in the documentation anywhere that guarantees that custom attributes will be returned in any particular order. If you need ordered attributes, add an `Order` member to your attribute class.

Comment: Or if the actual order doesn't matter, you just need the same order every time, regardless of what that order is, order by something that already exists (such as `Name` here)

Comment: Thanks, Yes, you're right, but I didn't say that is a .NET problem. Is there any solution or settings or any other thing to solve the problem from the base

Comment: @YasserMoradi What problem? That a function that makes no guarantees about the order of the items in its result is unpredictable when you look at the order of the items in its result? In my experience, in the vast majority of cases, order will be irrelevant, and that's what the API is designed for. It's you who sees this as a problem, who cares about order, so it's you that gets to sort. Perhaps you can expand your question to explain why order matters to you, and perhaps in that case, there will be a better approach.

Comment: @hvd Yes, as I said before, I'm talking about my problem.

Comment: @YasserMoradi I don't understand what your problem is, either. It's simple: Don't rely on the order of the attributes returned by the ```GetCustomAttributes``` method. If you want an order, you need to specify that yourself.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, as I said this is not a method problem, this is my problem. Reflection is a part of my Visual Studio Plugin, which performs some magics(!) which power of attributes.
At the moment, I've developed a extension method which sorts based on any mechanism that attributes provide, such as .NET Built-in interfaces implementations on custom attributes to make sort possible based on different attributes implementations. I will try to find better solution, but for now my code is OK, thank you all for your suggestions. and at least I know this is not my fault, and order is not guaranteed.